# What hardware should I use to mount outside window screens?

Tags: windows, hardware, screens

We recently moved into a home with many double hung windows. The previous owners originally had screens with plunger pins (see below), but they said it became a maintenance issue (I guess because water was getting in the holes when the screens weren't up?). So they had aluminum covers put on all the frames, blocking the holes.

[image: plunger pin]

I'm looking for hardware to mount new screens that:

- won't leave open holes in the window frames
- mounts on the outside of the windows
- allows the screens to be installed from inside (example of how that can work [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8MmV6avL7s))
- fits tight enough to keep out bugs

I've considered FlexScreens (expensive and really probably need a channel/pocket), 3M dual lock (not tight enough to keep out bugs), and casement clips (require mounting from outside).

It seems like springs with channels (like in the video of inside mounting screen) might work if we can add channels, but no one I've talked to seems to think that's possible.

Does anyone have advice or suggestions?

Photos of the actual window:

[image: window]

[image: window]

Answer (score 1):

Best bet would be to plan on using the screen hangers similar to the ones shown below from Lowe's mounted on the outside top of the window and screen.

[image]

You can hook the screen to the top trim from the inside and then let it drop closed. Watch out for your fingers. Secure the screen with a simple hook and eye lock on the inside of the window. If you plan it right, the screens will be interchangable with windows the same size.

[image]